# Solr 1.4 wildcard queries on a multiValued field

Tags: solr, full-text-search, wildcard

I have a field set up like this;

`<field name="keywordPhrases" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />`

But I cannot seem to perform wildcard queries on it;

`keywordPhrases:smok*`

Is there are way around this?

I'm using Solr 1.4